# All children of this widget must have a key(edit:)

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blN94.png)I am trying to make a ReorderableListView, which needs a key. I put it, however it returns the error "All children of this widget must have a key". Can anyone help me? (I've seen similar problems here but I still couldn't solve it)

```
ReorderableListView(
                  onReorder: _onReorder,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: dias.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            key: ValueKey(dias[index]),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            child: _cartaodia(context, index),
                          );
                        }
                    ),
              ],
              )
```

edit: I saw some examples that used the key of this form, however the index it does not recognize the index as shown in the image

Answer (score 0):

Your listViewBuilder also require Key.

```
ListView.builder(
  key: Key(dias.length.toString()), // added line
     itemCount: dias.length,
```

Update:

```
 ConstrainedBox(//  added widget
          constraints:
              BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
          key: Key("Const"),
          child: ListView.builder(
              // add the value key inside the list view instead
              key: ValueKey("list"),
              itemCount: 50,
              //   shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: Text("hello"),
                );
              }),
        ),
```

Comment: returns a new error: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Comment: Use shrinkwrap:true in listview.

Comment: I did it and he didn't report any errors but I can't scroll the screen

Comment: you have to wrap your listview with ConstrainedBox as show in update also remove shrinkwrap from listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `ValueKey` inside the `ListView.builder` widget instead.

Like this:

```
ReorderableListView(
        onReorder: _onReorder,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            // add the value key inside the list view instead
              key: ValueKey(dias[index]),
              itemCount: dias.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: _cartaodia(context, index),
                );
              }
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: I had tried, but report an error with the red line under the index. Do you know how I can solve this problem with the index?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you @JulisAraujo. What error are you still getting ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't express myself well. I attached an image that shows this